# How to output all contents of a list?

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is a concept I am trying to understand for my program. The following code has been altered for explanation purposes. Hope my goal is clear

```
Dim List As New List(Of String)() 'the size and contents of the list is not constant
Dim test As String

List.Add("Hello")
List.Add("World")

    test = Nothing
    For Each test In errorsList
        Console.WriteLine(test) ' outputs "Hello" and "World"

    Next
    MsgBox(test) 'Outputs "World"
```

How can I have `test` output both `"Hello"` and `"World"` so that I can use it later on in my code?

Comment: `String.Join(...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
test = String.Join(" ", list)
```

before MsgBox

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're overwriting the string each time, whereas you need to be extending it, but adding the next item on the list to it.

As suggested above, you can use `String.Join(" ", list)`.

There are other ways you can concatenate a string, using an ampersand is one (&). Why not just output the list in the messagebox, is that no easier?

Comment: If I output `list.toString` in a message box I get "System.Collections.Generic.List"

Comment: @RogerRivas Harambe did not say anything about `list.ToString()`. Also, commentary on this answer, I wouldn't use & for a list, in case more elements are added. `String.Join` and `IEnumberable.Aggregate(Of String)()` (or StringBuilder) will support larger collections of strings than just two elements and should be preferred when growth is possible.